# problem with IN and LIKE in SQL when arguments contain special characters for a language

Tags: sql, t-sql, special-characters

I’ve got such a KeyWord table (MS SQL):

- KeyGuid Qualifier PrimitiveKey
- DA7E4E27-FDE5-4D43-A365-8A789164A816 tit kirkäna
- EED58875-FE41-4A18-A93C-A44AA62CEEEE htit kirkänbh
- A0EB795E-EE23-4990-BAB9-897C93C70CE3 htit  kirkänah
- F7F4632B-AC82-4DEB-B966-BBA8EF4D2C9E tit  kirkänb
- C0EB795E-EE23-4990-BAB9-897C93C70CE3 nam  kirkänas
- E2F4632B-AC82-4DEB-B966-BBA8EF4D2C9E nam  kirkänbs
- A222795E-EE23-4990-BAB9-897C93C70CE3 tit  kirkacb
- B333632B-AC82-4DEB-B966-BBA8EF4D2C9E tit  kirkaca
- 1222795E-EE23-4990-BAB9-897C93C70C81 htit  kirkacbh
- E533632B-AC82-4DEB-B966-BBA8EF4D2C82 htit  kirkacah

This simplest query properly returns all relevant records:

```
select * from KeyWord where PrimitiveKey like 'kirkän%'
```

- DA7E4E27-FDE5-4D43-A365-8A789164A816 tit  kirkäna
- EED58875-FE41-4A18-A93C-A44AA62CEEEE htit  kirkänbh
- A0EB795E-EE23-4990-BAB9-897C93C70CE3 htit  kirkänah
- F7F4632B-AC82-4DEB-B966-BBA8EF4D2C9E tit  kirkänb
- C0EB795E-EE23-4990-BAB9-897C93C70CE3 nam  kirkänas
- E2F4632B-AC82-4DEB-B966-BBA8EF4D2C9E nam  kirkänbs

I use such a query to limit the resutls to match specific qualifiers:

```
select * from KeyWord where Qualifier IN ('tit', 'htit') and PrimitiveKey Like 'kirkac%'
```

which works perfectly:

- A222795E-EE23-4990-BAB9-897C93C70CE3 tit  kirkacb
- B333632B-AC82-4DEB-B966-BBA8EF4D2C9E tit  kirkaca
- 1222795E-EE23-4990-BAB9-897C93C70C81 htit  kirkacbh
- E533632B-AC82-4DEB-B966-BBA8EF4D2C82 htit  kirkacah

However when the phrase contains a special character like ä it does not return results:

```
select * from KeyWord where Qualifier IN ('tit', 'htit') and PrimitiveKey Like 'kirkän%'
```

nor does it with the qualifiers limited like this:

```
select * from KeyWord where (Qualifier = 'tit' OR Qualifier = 'htit') and PrimitiveKey Like 'kirkän%'
```

However it does work like this:

```
select * from KeyWord where (Qualifier like 'tit' OR Qualifier like 'htit') PrimitiveKey Like 'kirkän%'
```

- DA7E4E27-FDE5-4D43-A365-8A789164A816 tit  kirkäna
- EED58875-FE41-4A18-A93C-A44AA62CEEEE htit  kirkänbh
- A0EB795E-EE23-4990-BAB9-897C93C70CE3 htit  kirkänah
- F7F4632B-AC82-4DEB-B966-BBA8EF4D2C9E tit  kirkänb

What is wrong with the IN approach?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to use unicode compatible datatypes. Declaring the PrimitiveKey column as nvarchar, try prefixing the string you want to match with an 'N' like this:
select * from KeyWord where (Qualifier like 'tit' OR Qualifier like 'htit') and PrimitiveKey Like N'kirkän%' .

Comment: Prefixing does not help. Columns are declared as 'nvarchar'.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179886.aspx

basically LIKE operand has it:s own collation that overrides the server and column settings.  However i haven't been able to figure out where or if there is a way to change this setting.  The above article is a pretty tough read, but i think the most detailed explanation is at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably best handled with a specific collation setting that copes with the language-specific characters.

Here's an article on SQL Server collation that may help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174903(SQL.80).aspx

Comment: Collation has been checked. I have the same collation for the DB and columns of the table I am querying. Server collation is different but I checked that it is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at [Full-Text Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx). I know changing the collation would help here, as Neil says, but you might get some benefit out of using FTS depending on how scalable your implementation needs to be.

Comment: Full-Text Search might be an option but we need a quick solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have done more investigation on the problem. Here's what I found.

A. The problematic query actually returns results but containing 'ae' only:

```
select * from KeyWord where Qualifier IN ('tit', 'htit') and PrimitiveKey Like 'kirkän%'
```

returns for example 'kirkaeni'.

B. If another % is included in the query (for example: Like 'ki%rkän%') the results include those expected! (this is weird) (but also those not wanted, matching the other %, of course).

C. I have tried to reproduce the problem - creating a simple DB only with two tables (the one with 'kirk' stuff has a foreign key to the other one), I have used queries creating the problematic DB as well those creating tables, I have set the same collation (German_PhoneBook_CI_AI) + I have created indexes as in the problematic DB. However the problem did not occur, so I cannot yet actually reproduce it.

Any new ideas with these symptoms?